# Need to Remove Duplicate Posts in a Foreach Loop

Tags: wordpress, foreach, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I'm working on a site where major categories have different professions registered under them. When you click on a particular category (let's take Music for example), you will see all professionals registered under that category. To achieve this, I created a user taxonomy called **Profession**. A user can have more than one profession under a category. Whenever I query akk professionals in a category, I get duplicate posts which I can't seem to stop. Here is my foreach loop:

```
   <?php

    $users = get_objects_in_term( array(104, 106), 'profession' ); // there are too user ids listed in the array

    if ( !empty( $users ) ) {
     foreach ( $users as $user_id ) { 
   ?>

  <div>
      ...HTML CODES...
  </div>
  <!-- End Loop -->

      <?php } 
  } 
  else { ?>
    <p><br><br><?php _e('No registered user in this profession.'); ?></p>
  <?php } ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us the query that generates the duplicates.It's always best to solve these things at source rather than solving the symptoms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the PHP function array_unique to remove your duplicated user id's, like this:

```
$users = array_unique(get_objects_in_term( array(104, 106), 'profession' ));
```

The rest of your code will work just fine.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you!